# Computer won't boot with ethernet cable plugged in

Tags: motherboard

I just bought and installed an ASUS Z97-P motherboard, and it doesn't boot up (doesn't even allow me to go into BIOS) if I turn it on with the ethernet cable plugged in.

I've tried disabling/enabling every network-related option in the BIOS (not much), but still all I get is a black screen with a white cursor near the top left corner of the screen. If I unplug the ethernet at this stage, it proceeds to boot (and then I can enter BIOS).

This is with the computer plugged directly to one of the network wall-sockets in my apartment. What could be causing this? Is bad socket/cable an option? Anything I can tweak in the board/BIOS?

Comment: Odd things to try. Connect the cable, but do not connect it to the wall. does it boot then?  Jump into the asus bios, disable entirely the nic itself in the bios.  Now if you connect to the wall and it still fails ,  then you could have a problem with power passing wrong ways , which could be your computer, or even  via another computer improperly grounded or some other odd power stuff on the rest of the network.  Next you would get a voltmeter out and try and find out what is so screwed up.  Plugging the cable in after it does boot when there is power going wrong ways, might be unwise.

Comment: It only fails to boot when the (red) led in the ethernet port is on, for which I need to plug the cable to the wall and activate the NIC in the BIOS. As I said in another comment, it works when I plug it to switch/hub, so maybe it's the wall socket (of which I've tried a couple) which is causing this, but I would never expect a motherboard to react in this way...

Answer (score 1):

1. A blinking/static cursor looks like a hardware issue but despite that I would try first updating your motherboard firmware.
2. Next you should consider some ground loop or thing like that; is your PC frame grounded or not?
3. Next you can consider a faulty switch/hub (unlikely)
4. Finally considering your motherboard is new you might be dealing with a faulty Ethernet module.

Comment: (1) The cursor is not blinking. (2) I don't think it's grounded, but it's plugged to a standard grounded power socket. (3,4) If I plug it to a switch/hub instead of directly to the wall, it works.

Comment: 1) Edited blinking/static cursor 2) you can test for ground loops alternatively isolating the ground connector.  3/4) if a direct connection to a hub works I would stop using your wall RJ45; that connection can present either a ground loop, shortcut, antenna effect, etc etc. fix the cable that feeds your wallet RJ45 from the corresponding hub